# difference between withRegion() and withEndpointConfiguration() method in aws s3 or sqs client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

what is difference between `withRegion()` and `withEndpointConfiguration()` method in *aws S3* or *SQS* client.

UsingEndpointConfiguration needs *endPoint* and *signingRegion*. Is this *signingRegion* same as of s3 bucket? If yes, then why we need to specify it twice as region will be part of endpoint also. 
**Example**: `us-west-2` in `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @DownVoter. Please comment on why you downvoted and how this question could be improved.

Answer (score 6):

withEndpointConfiguration() is used with S3 clones (either on your localhost, Minio, etc.). It is also used with DynamoDB when installed on your local system.

Here is an example using Minio. The region "us-east-1" is just emulated for this API call.

```
EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(
                "http://192.168.178.84:9000", "us-east-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `withRegion()` or `withEndpointConfiguration()`. If you use `withRegion()` it's not mandated to use `withEndpointConfiguration()`, because the AWS api will take care of the remaining(forming the endpoint). if you are using `withEndpointConfiguration()`, the parameters of `EndpointConfiguration(String serviceEndpoint,String signingRegion)` are both the type of string, the AWS api won't create a substring to get the region from the first parameter, as Region is a mandated one, otherwise it will use the `DEFAULT_REGION_PROVIDER` to set the Region. For more see [AwsClientBuilder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#withRegion-com.amazonaws.regions.Regions-)